# Angular material pagination isn't working probably when two tables exist

Tags: angular

I have an issue with material pagination if there are two tables: 
the problem seems to be like this one: [Multiple material pagination in one component doesn't work in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428605/multiple-material-pagination-in-one-component-doesnt-work-in-angular)

i tried to implement the solution in above link, but in the console it give me:

> this.paginator.toArray is not a function

here's my implementation:

```
  customerTblArray: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  UnitModelsTblArray: MatTableDataSource<any>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();



 constructor(private _getCustSrv: GetCustomersService,  private _getUnitModels: GetUnitModelsService) {
    this._getCustSrv.GetAllCustomers().subscribe(r => {
      this.customerTblArray = new MatTableDataSource(r["result"]);
    });

    this._getUnitModels.GetAllUnitModels().subscribe(r => {
      this.UnitModelsTblArray = new MatTableDataSource(r["result"]);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.customerTblArray.paginator = this.paginator.toArray()[0];
    this.UnitModelsTblArray.paginator = this.paginator.toArray()[1];
  }
```

.HTML code is very large, i use bootstrap modal to show up the content, at the end of each modal i put:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="3">
</mat-paginator>
```

but in the console shows an error:

> this.paginator.toArray is not a function

even that all content are loaded correctly with material table except the pagination i doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of: `@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();`

put: `@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();`

it will be enough.